# How to add windows terminal to registry with extra commandline arguments?

Tags: windows-registry, regedit, windows-terminal

I've added the `wt.exe` to my right click context menu through `regedit`. I've put it in here-

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell`

-> Create new folder and name it anything, preferably **Windows Terminal** or **Terminal**

-> Create a new folder named **command** and set the value string's data to `"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe"`

This all works fine, and clicking on terminal inside the context menu will open the terminal as expected. But I'd like to commandline arguments such as `wt -d . ; new-tab -d C:\ pwsh.exe` or `wt -p "Windows PowerShell" -d . ; split-pane -V wsl.exe`. How can I add these to the registry value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that best way to do this is create a `.bat` file and paste the command there-
`start wt -p "Windows PowerShell" -d . ; split-pane -V wsl.exe`

Then paste the absolute path of the `.bat` file to the registry key.